# Installing Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle into Php Bolt CMS

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, bolt-cms

I've trying figure out how to install `Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle` into PHP Bolt CMS and take advantage of Boostrap Twig Templates Tags for my Bolt theme. But sadly come to a dead-end at install. :(

Since both are based on the Symfony Framework, the idea of adding `"braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.0"` to my `composer.json`, ignore the Assetic Management part and adding the following to `app/AppKernel.php` sounded possible.

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel {
    public function registerBundles() {
        $bundles = array(new Braincrafted\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\BraincraftedBootstrapBundle());
        return $bundles;
    }
}
```

**But where is "`class AppKernel extends Kernel`" in my Php Bolt Application?**
I'm guessing the `index.php` would be a start, or should I build a Php Bolt Extension path?

All I want is:

```
{{ knp_menu_render(menu, { 'style': 'tabs' }) }}
```

and

```
<form action="..." method="..." class="form-horizontal">
    {{ bootstrap_set_style('horizontal') }}

    {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
    {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}

    {{ bootstrap_set_style('') }}
</form> 
{{ label_success('Success') }}
```

Thanks to anyone for help. 
P.S  Php Bolt is +1 for ME so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bolt CMS is based on [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) PHP micro-framework, which in turn is based on Symfony **components**, not Symfony Framework. There are not any bundles, but Silex's [`ServiceProvider`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers.html)s. Furthermore, Bolt does not take an advantage of Security component.

Bolt CMS is expandable with extensions, but also it's possible to override built-in service providers - you only have to register your own provider under the same name, right after `$app->initialize()` (you need some app architecture tweaks).

Please refer to Silex documentation for more information about registering service providers.